# Flutter/dart accessing listdata within another list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON response from RestApi like this:

```
    [{"_id":"5eee4b3630cff64ee216e4fb",
"assignee_user_id":"5eab4a435647780af311d3a7",
"task_name":"Another Test work",
"task_description":"Test Description",
"assignee_name":"Test Assignee",
"status":"assigned",
"assignment_date":"20-06-2020 11:15",
"assignor_name":"Test Assignor",
"assignor_remarks":[{"commentTime":"21-06-2020 05:17","comment":"Test Comment"}]}]
```

and the podo class build is like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Work> workFromMap(String str) => List<Work>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Work.fromMap(x)));

String workToMap(List<Work> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Work {
    Work({
        this.id,
        this.assigneeUserId,
        this.taskName,
        this.taskDescription,
        this.assigneeName,
        this.status,        
        this.assignmentDate,
        this.assignorName,        
        this.assignorRemarks,
    });

    String id;
    String assigneeUserId;
    String taskName;
    String taskDescription;
    String assigneeName;
    String status;    
    String assignmentDate;
    String assignorName;
   
    List<AssignorRemark> assignorRemarks;

    factory Work.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Work(
        id: json["_id"],
        assigneeUserId: json["assignee_user_id"],
        taskName: json["task_name"],
        taskDescription: json["task_description"],
        assigneeName: json["assignee_name"],
        status: json["status"],        
        assignmentDate: json["assignment_date"],        
        assignorRemarks: List<AssignorRemark>.from(json["assignor_remarks"].map((x) => AssignorRemark.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "_id": id,
        "assignee_user_id": assigneeUserId,
        "task_name": taskName,
        "task_description": taskDescription,
        "assignee_name": assigneeName,
        "status": status,        
        "assignment_date": assignmentDate,        
        "assignor_remarks": List<dynamic>.from(assignorRemarks.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}

class AssignorRemark {
    AssignorRemark({
        this.commentTime,
        this.comment,
    });

    String commentTime;
    String comment;

    factory AssignorRemark.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AssignorRemark(
        commentTime: json["commentTime"],
        comment: json["comment"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "commentTime": commentTime,
        "comment": comment,
    };
}
```

and my api call is like this:

```
import './work.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Work>> fetchWork() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final userid = prefs.getString('user_id');
  final response =
      await http.get("https://myserver/api/work-monitor/work/?id=$userid",
    );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    print(response.body);
    
    
    return workFromMap(response.body);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Profile');
  }
}
```

and my screen file content is like this:

```
class WorkMonitor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkMonitorState createState() => _WorkMonitorState();
}

class _WorkMonitorState extends State<WorkMonitor> {
  Future<Work> futureMyWorkMonitor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Work Monitor'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchWork(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  Work work = snapshot.data[index];
                  //  return Text('${work.taskName}');
                  return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Subject: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        )),
                                    Text(
                                      '${work.taskName}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                              Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Description: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        )),
                                    Flexible(
                                        child: Text(
                                      '${work.taskDescription}',
                                    )),
                                  ]),
                              Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Assigned Date: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        )),
                              Text(
                                '${work.assignmentDate}' ?? " ",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                                  ]),

                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Description: ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        )),
                              Text(
                                '${work.status}' ?? "Gone",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                                  ]),
                            
                            Text(
                              
                              '${work.assignorRemarks[index]}'
                              ),
                            ]),
                            
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }

            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Only issue I am facing here is, I am not able to access/iterate over comments. How I can do this?

Comment: Why can't you access/iterate over comments? What error are you getting?

Comment: @puelo - very new to flutter, I am just trying to access like `'${work.assignorRemarks}' `and I am getting like an instance of `AssignorRemark'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow also iterate through each comment inside each list item. One way (probably only for a small amount of remarks), would be a `Column` (or if you need scrolling you could use a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column`). Example:

```
Column(
  children: work.assignorRemarks.map<Text>((remark) {
    return Text(remark.comment);
  }).toList()
)
```

If you have a lot of items you are probably better of using a nested `ListView`

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working. how I can add the comment as well, which is child of `assignorRemarks`. can I do a return another column instead of Text and then have two Text widgets.

Comment: You mean the `commentTime` ?

Comment: There are variety to Widgets you could use to display this nested information. You cannot nest it inside the Text widget tho. I would recommend: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html. Or you build one String for the information: `Text('${remark.comment} (${remark.commentTime})');`

Comment: Thanks.that will do. but only issue with this is like, I want the comment font- little smaller. is that possible with this solution?

Comment: Thanks Puelo for you help, I used the `map<Row>(remark){` and then used two Text widgets inside `Row widget`